# One Checkbox is selecting other in ListView Android Studio

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin

Before anything else let me know you I am new in Android app development.

When I am selecting one checkbox it automatically selects another checkbox after 10 items.
Means if I select first it selects 11th, 21st, 31st and so on automatically.

XML of ListView

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/lstContacts"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

private class ViewHolder {
        TextView displayName;
        TextView phoneNumber;
        TextView contactID;
        CheckBox cchecked;
    }
```

Custom Adapter

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = vi.inflate(R.layout.contactmodel, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.displayName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cname);
            holder.phoneNumber = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cnumber);
            holder.contactID = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cid);
            holder.cchecked = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cchecked);


            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ContactsInfo contactsInfo = (ContactsInfo) contactsInfoList.get(position);
        holder.displayName.setText(contactsInfo.getDisplayName());
        holder.phoneNumber.setText(contactsInfo.getPhoneNumber());
        holder.contactID.setText(contactsInfo.getContactId());
        holder.cchecked.setTag(contactsInfo.getContactId());
        holder.cchecked.setText(contactsInfo.getContactId());



        return convertView;
    }
```

ContactModel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/cardview"

    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    card_view_cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    card_view_cardElevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/crl">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/cimg"
            android:layout_width="60dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_person_24" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cname"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:textColor="@color/color_text_primary"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cimg"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:id="@+id/cnumber"
            android:padding="2dp"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/cimg"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/cimg" />

        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cchecked"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cid"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/cnumber"
            android:layout_marginStart="1dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/cimg" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Showcontacts activity

```
ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
    String contactId = null;
    String displayName = null;
    contactsInfoList = new ArrayList<ContactsInfo>();
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {

                ContactsInfo contactsInfo = new ContactsInfo();
                contactId = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                displayName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                contactsInfo.setContactId(contactId);
                contactsInfo.setDisplayName(displayName);

                Cursor phoneCursor = getContentResolver().query(
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                        null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                        new String[]{contactId},
                        null);

                if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                    String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));

                    contactsInfo.setPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
                }

                phoneCursor.close();

                contactsInfoList.add(contactsInfo);

            }
        }
    }
    cursor.close();

    dataAdapter = new MyCustomAdapter(showcontacts.this, R.layout.contactmodel, contactsInfoList);
    listView.setAdapter((ListAdapter) dataAdapter);
```

Comment: You need to set the checked status in your ``ViewHolder`` when you're updating it to display the current data (``setText`` etc). View holders get reused to display different list items, so you have to fully update what info they're displaying

Comment: Oh also since you're new at it, the modern way to do this is with a ``RecyclerView`` (https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) which is specifically built for this reuse-a-view-holder idea. In its adapter, you set your data on the views in ``onBindViewHolder`` and that's where you'd check/uncheck the box as appropriate for each item